# picking up information server side with redirected pages

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, form-submit

I have a page (abc.aspx) which I am dynamically (via javascript) directing to a specific url.  My question is, lets say I specify the page to hit (in the action) as verify.aspx.  I then submit the form to verify.aspx, the onload function runs, how do I get at the form field values that were submitted from abc.aspx?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this with a property of the Page that is a piece of the Request object

`Request.Form`

Represents a collection of all the goodies you are after.